# Moscow Institute of Physics and Technology Mathematics Competition Question

Tags: reference-request, recreational-mathematics

As mentioned in the title, does anyone know where can I obtain past question papers from Moscow Institute of Physics and Technology?

Any link will be greatly appreciated.

The following is one of the questions from the institute:

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix with real entries and let $H=\frac{A+A^T}{2}$. Assume that $H$ is positive definite. Prove that $\det(H) \leq \det(A)$

I do not obtain the question from the institute directly, but from some problem sets. I would like to try out questions from the institute.

Comment: search here http://www.abitu.ru/olimp/konk/a_5tltu7.html

Comment: and here (1998-2004)
http://mipt.ru/dmcp/abiturs/taskbook.php